# Create a new JDBC driver with netbeans to connect to Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

When I run the main class I get these errors:

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver.<clinit>(CassandraDriver.java:52)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
at oracledbtest.CqlJdbcTestBasic.main(CqlJdbcTestBasic.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

How can I create a new driver connection to Cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? The error simply means that you do not have slf4j's jar in your classpath..